# Passing multiple dataframes into function to produce dataframe using map_dfr

Tags: r

I have a function which I am passing three variables (column names) and a dataframe and putting the results into a dataframe with `map_dfr` which works fine.

```
library(tidyverse)

iris_median<-function(df, col){
    df%>%
        summarise(Median=median(.data[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))%>%
        mutate(field=as.character(!!col))
}

median_df <- map_dfr(c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width",
                       "Petal.Length"), .f=iris_median,
                     df= iris)
```

When I try to pass multiple dataframes into this function as below:

```
iris1 <- iris [1:50,]
iris2 <- iris [51:100,]

median_df <- map_dfr("Sepal.Length", .f=iris_median,
                     df= c(iris1, iris2))
```

I get the error message: `no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "list"`

I don't understand why it isn't just iterating through the two different dataframes and doing the calculation for each dataframe.

Can anyone ammend the code?

Comment: The `map` functions are only vectorized over the first parameter. Do you want to be able to pass multiple data.frames and multiple columns? Exactly what do you want the output to be in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map_dfr` iterates through the items in the first argument (the `.x` argument). It will not iterate through the additional arguments passed via `...`.

Since the `map_` functions are just wrappers for a loop, your call

```r
map_dfr("Sepal.Length", .f = iris_median, df = c(iris1, iris2))
```

calls the `iris_median` function *once* (since the first argument has length 1), and passes the whole list to the `df` argument at once. This is equivalent to

```r
iris_median(df = c(iris1, iris2), col = "Sepal.Length")
```

And it is this call that causes your error, since you are trying to `summarize` a `list`.

To get `map_dfr` to work on a list of data frames, you need to pass the list as the first (`.x`) argument, and the single column name as an additional argument:

```r
map_dfr(.x = list(iris1, iris2),
        .f = iris_median, 
        col = "Sepal.Length")
#>   Median        field
#> 1    5.0 Sepal.Length
#> 2    5.9 Sepal.Length
```

If you want to iterate through *both* a list of data frames *and* a vector of column names you need `map2_dfr`, which iterates through the first *two* arguments.

```r
map2_dfr(.x = list(iris1, iris2), 
         .y = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width"), 
         .f = iris_median)
#>   Median        field
#> 1    5.0 Sepal.Length
#> 2    1.3  Petal.Width
```

---

**Update**

Note that `map2_dfr` iterates through the `.x` and `.y` arguments in parallel. If you want all possible combinations of the data frames and column names, you would need to pass the data frames and column names through `cross` first.

```r
df_list <- list(iris1, iris2)
col_vec <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")

cross(.l = list(df_list, col_vec)) %>%
  map_dfr(~ iris_median(.x[[1]], .x[[2]]))
#>   Median        field
#> 1    5.0 Sepal.Length
#> 2    5.9 Sepal.Length
#> 3    3.4  Sepal.Width
#> 4    2.8  Sepal.Width
```

Comment: So am I right in thinking map2_dfr doesn't iterate through both the df's and column names? It iterates through the df's and then applies the column names in order. eg for iris1 the column Sepal.Length is used and then for iris2, Petal.Width is used for the function. For completeness, is there a map function that will iterate through both df's and colnames so for iris1 to use both Sepal.Length and Petal.Width and the same for iris2. So the resulting df will have 4 rows...

Comment: @Basil no - you would need to generate the combinations beforehand using `cross`, which is quite straightforward. See my update